# Ranger and Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I have a three node cluster which both Kerberos and Ranger is installed on it.

I am just a bit confused regarding one use case which I use as an ordinary  user (tom). I have the `hdfs.headless.keytab` and `hbase.headless.keytab`  files in my /home/tom so I can use

```
[tom@master keytabs]$ ls /home/tom -l
total 8
-r--r----- 1 tom tom 373 Oct 26 02:32 hbase.headless.keytab
-r--r----- 1 tom tom 368 Nov  8 18:59 hdfs.headless.keytab
```

So if I want to write to HDFS, I can always initiate a Kerberos ticket by above files:

```
[tom@master root]$ klist
klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500)
[tom@master keytabs]$ kinit -kt /home/tom/hdfs.headless.keytab hdfs-bazargani_lab@BAZARGANI.COM
[tom@master keytabs]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500
Default principal: hdfs-bazargani_lab@BAZARGANI.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/08/18 19:12:10  11/09/18 19:12:10  krbtgt/BAZARGANI.COM@BAZARGANI.COM
        renew until 11/08/18 19:12:10
```

Now I want to activate the ticket for HBase:

```
[tom@master keytabs]$ kinit -kt /home/tom/hbase.headless.keytab hbase-bazargani_lab@BAZARGANI.COM
[tom@master keytabs]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500
Default principal: hbase-bazargani_lab@BAZARGANI.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/08/18 19:30:01  11/09/18 19:30:01  krbtgt/BAZARGANI.COM@BAZARGANI.COM
        renew until 11/08/18 19:30:01
```

Now while I run below commands (writing to HDFS) I get:

```
[tom@master keytabs]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /tom
mkdir: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/tom":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

I am not sure why I can't do the above while I have had init'ed the ticket for HDFS before HBase as well for tom when I writing to HDFS it now considers it as HBase user and won't let me write to HDFS..I can't su to hdfs because I don't know the password..Can someone explain how I can setup a principal named `tom` which can do both HBase and HDFS ticket actions?

Comment: what is the permission on folder tom ?, try to make it chmod 777 and execute the command and see if it resolves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the better way to you can do would be, create a key tab called "tom.headless.keytab" and principal "tom@bozxxx"
I am assuming user tom is already available on Ranger , if not you can sync the user (based on how Ranger is configured, whether it is configured to read from a file or read from Unix user or from Ldap)  or the shortcut is just create user "tom" from Ranger UI. once user is crated, give access to user tom on HDFS and HBASE. then do Kinit then you can run your command

Comment: post a comment, if you need more details

Comment: Hi, how kereberos know to map "tom.headless.keytab" and principal "tom@bozxxx" to my tom user on linux -CentOs?

Comment: sorry for the late response when you create principal with name "tom@xxxx" and make user "tom" as owner of that key tab kerberos will identify that